# How to write nUnit/Moq for testing generic extension methods?

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit, moq

I have the following generic extension method for deleting all EntityObjects from an ObjectContext

```
public static void DeleleAllObjects<TEntity>(this ObjectContext context)
        where TEntity : EntityObject
    {
        var objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        objectSet.ToList().ForEach(e => objectSet.DeleteObject(e));
    }
```

I'm fairly new to TDD and using nUnit/Moq...but I'm not sure where to being to write tests for this method?

Comment: I think you have first create [TestFixtureSetup] creating the context object, with predefined number of objectsets. Then after this function call you can assert to objectset.count to 0. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExtensionTest
{
    public class FakeEntity : EntityObject
    {

    }

    [Test]
    public void DeleteAllObjects()
    {
        //arrange
        var objectsToDelete = new List<FakeEntity>
            {
                new FakeEntity(),
                new FakeEntity()
            };
        var mockContext = new Mock<ObjectContext>();
        var mockObjectSet = new Mock<ObjectSet<FakeEntity>>();
        mockObjectSet.Setup(x => x.ToList()).Returns(objectsToDelete);
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.CreateObjectSet<FakeEntity>()).Returns(mockObjectSet.Object);

        //act
        mockContext.Object.DeleteAllObjects<FakeEntity>();

        //assert
        mockContext.Verify(x => x.CreateObjectSet<FakeEntity>(), Times.Once());
        mockObjectSet.Verify(x => x.ToList(), Times.Once());
        mockObjectSet.Verify(x => x.DeleteObject(It.IsAny<FakeEntity>()), Times.Exactly(2));

    }
}
```

Now, this is assuming all your mocked types (the context and the object set) have the methods you invoke declared as `virtual` or the classes are `abstract`. Mocking interfaces is usually less restrictive.

Also, if you want to get more picky with your asserts to ensure that indeed `DeleteObject` is called first with the first instance, and then with the second, and not twice on the first, then you could change that part of the test. But this should serve as a pretty good starting point.

**To summarize:**

This particular test should only really test the code within your extension method. Meaning, it should only ensure that you call `CreateObjectSet<>()`, get the list, and then call `DeleteObject` on each one.

It should not care at all if indeed the `DeleteObject()` altered the `ObjectSet` or not (in fact it won't, since it's a mock). That should be the responsibility of a test for the `DeleteObject()` method, but since I'm assuming that is actually an EF method, you should not write a test for third party components.

Comment: `Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: `  on CreateObjectSet...which is non-virtual :(

Comment: I see, well, in that case your best option is probably to extract an interface from the context and have your extension method apply to the interface, see here for more info:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1894066/1373170 
and also here: http://blog.voltje.be/2012/11/19/mocking-entity-framework-using-objectcontext-and-database-first/
or if you are using EF Code first: http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/

Comment: Hmmm...not sure I want to create a repository JUST so I can create a single method that can be tested?  Might actually be simpler in test to add a local DB to the test project and add/remove items to it?

Comment: Right. Well actually, you would need the interface to test anything, such as a Controller depending on this context as well. I'm currently too accustomed to unit testing as part of my process, so I would go the extra mile to have my code testable, not just for the extension method but for everything.