# Testing Linq Queries EF and the Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, repository-pattern

Trust me, I've read many articles and questions here on SO. But I haven't found a satisfactory answer.
Take [Matt Robert's Tutorial](http://moleseyhill.com/blog/2009/06/29/simple-repository-pattern/) on the repository pattern and unit testing as an example:

I don't get it.. do both repositories contain the exact same query logic? It appears to be so, and if so how is that a useful pattern? It would mean whenever I change the query in the fake repository, I have to change the query logic in the actual repository - that sounds like a PITA and recipe for problems.

I would like to keep the query in *one* method and test that method. It later occurred to me, I could do like this:

```
//Student can be from the db or a fake list
public person GetStudent(IEnumerable<Student> students,int studentid)
{
   return students.FirstOrDefault(s =>s.PersonId ==studentid);
}

//unit test
    Assert.IsNull(GetStudent(fakeStudentList, -1))
//actual code
    var student =  GetStudent(entities.students,-1)
```

Is there a pattern that mimics above? If so, what is it? Or is that in fact how the repository pattern works? If so, why does it feel like the repository pattern duplicates code?

And also, the *effort*.. look at this terrifying **[example](http://mylifeandcode.blogspot.ie/2012/10/unit-testing-with-mock-entity-framework.html)** :S?

Comment: Great question and great username (can't wait for book 13!).  +1

Comment: @Brian The book is out already :P

Comment: Duh... I meant book 14, and I see that **it** is already out too!

Comment: @Brian Yep, unfortunately I'm fighting with design patterns and testing to start reading :( But soon :P

Comment: I was going to say _write a unit test for your repository and just moq the context_. Then I read this answer and realised it's not that simple - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1894066/201648. However, I though the links in that answer might be useful to you.

Comment: @AaronNewton Yes, I was going to do that was mock the context but apparently that was "dangerous". And other examples are just overcomplicated. Thanks, I will have a look at that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much to go on, but I think you have a flaw in your repository pattern.

You should not pass in a student collection to `GetStudent()`.  `GetStudent` should be part of a class that internally knows about the student list - whether it's a file, `List`, database, whatever.

So your "fake" repository *may* have the same logic, or it *may* just return a hard-coded dummy `Student`.  If you're faking the repository I assume it because you're testing something else that needs the repository, so it shouldn't care *how* it got the `Student`.

Also the article you reference only mentions one repository, so I'm not sure why you're needing duplicating it.

Comment: If `GetStudent()` knows about the `Student` `list` or some data structure I think that's bad design. It shouldn't matter where the list of student is from - I should be able to test the query once. 
And about the article,that's because unfortunately I can't find examples where they implement both repositories. But implementing repositories gives the idea of duplication, I am still searching though.

Comment: It HAS to know about the underlying collection.  That's the point.  You may _initialize_ the repository in some way that gives it the underlying data, but it knows about it.  What's the point of having a repository method where you _hand_ it a collection of students and ask it "give me the one with an ID id x"?  Why not just do it yourself?  The point of the repository is to abstract away the underlying collection.

Comment: How is it bad design for a StudentRepository class to know about the database/repository? Otherwise, what's the point of the StudentRepository class?

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand. So does that mean I have to copy the code in the fake repository to the actual repository? How'd that work with unit testing..? Test with the fake repo, if it passes copy the query to the actual repo?

Comment: Testing what?  the repository?  Don't create a fake - test the ACTUAL repository (possibly faking out the data source if you can)  Testing something that USES the repository?  Then fake the repository but you don't HAVE to use the same logic - you can return hard-coded values if that works for your tests.

Comment: Think about it this way - you don't TEST fakes - you CREATE fakes that are used to test OTHER things.

Comment: Ok, does it make sense to think that the repository doesn't do any complex queries. Its job is to provide access to a group of related items or a single item. But it doesn't handle complex queries among different entities. It provides data that can be used by the calling method for more complex queries?

Comment: It shouldn´t matter what the repository does on the inside, you will test its interface, its outside contract. And if you need a fake, mock repository you don´t have to actually write complex queries, as you are faking the results. You can, of course, have repositories which do complex things on the inside.

Comment: The purpose of a `Foo` repository is to Create/Read/Update/Delete `Foo`s.  In a loosely-coupled design you don't care where the `Foo`s come from (or go), which is why a "fake" can return hard-coded `Foos`.  In your example you hand a list of `Foos` to `GetFoo()` which is pointless.  The complexity of the queries is irrelevant.  You shouldn't be "testing" your repository behavior using a fake `Foo` repository, you should be testing the behavior of a REAL `Foo` repository.

Comment: Tbh, I don't think I'm going to grok this anytime soon. @DStanley, not sure if you got my invite? Anyway, thanks. What you describe sounds like integration testing